# Can you explain to me this second way of instanciating an object in java?

Tags: java

i started learning java recently and there's on part that confuses me and i need help in.

from what i know to instanciate a java object this is the syntax

```
String s1 = new String("This is a string");
```

however the problem is lately ive come across stuff declared like this

```
NumberFormat numF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
```

Can someone explain this to me

Comment: Nothing to explain here. Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) of `getNumberInstance`, it returns a `NumberFormat` object.

Comment: This is called a *static factory method*. Check out *Effective Java 2nd Ed* Item 1 for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NumberFormat` is an abstract class, and so, you cannot instantiate it the "normal way".

Hence, it has provided a static method `getNumberInstance` so that you can get a "general-purpose number format".

In your code, you are using that same method, to get an instance of `NumberFormat`

Also, this:

```
NumberFormat numF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
```

is the same as calling this:

```
NumberFormat numF = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
```

Comment: There is no "hence" about providing a static factory method - plenty of abstract classes don't. I would suggest you remove that word.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah, they don't want to provide a general purpose instance of themselves.

Comment: @AndyTurner is hence really a bad word choice? I think of it as a synonym for "for this reason" or "so"; not as "if this then always"